# Why won't the event trigger when I emit with socket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io, event-handling

I have an event I am trying to trigger that's called '**usernames**'.
I am using the Socket.IO library in Node.js. So I have 2 files, index.html and server.js:

**The event I am trying to emit is on the client side in index.html:**

```
    //show online users
    socket.on('usernames', function (data) {
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length() ; i++) {
            html += data[i] + '<br/>';
        }

        $users.html(html);
    });
```

**The emit is on the server side in server.js :**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //new user join
    socket.on('new user', function (data, callback) {
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1) { //if name dont exist .indexOf() returns -1
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
            io.sockets.emit('usernames', nicknames);
        }
    });
     // sent message from user
    socket.on('send message', function (data) {
        //send the data to all users
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
    //
});
```

**The event in index.html is inside $(document).ready();

Nothing happens, the event won't trigger.

Help ?

Comment: You shouldn't use spaces in event name. Is the event "new user" ever called? If not the you never emit "usernames"

Comment: Actually it works ok with spaces, maybe it's not best practice but it definatly works.

Comment: You have an event that triggers when an emit named 'usernames' is fired. I can see in your server side code you are emitting an event called 'usernames' inside an event called 'new user'. Is new user being called somewhere else? If not, that would be a good place to start. Also I see in your server you are pushing each username into a nicknames array but the nicknames array isn't present in this snippet of code, unless however you just haven't included that as part of this example

Comment: @Jackthomson Thank you for the good observation. I didn't fire the event 'new user'. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. 
There were 2 errors:
1) The statement 'data.length()' didn't compile, the correct way is using 'data.length'.
2) I didn't fire 'new user' event hence the 'usernames' event didn't trigger.